# Price demanded and offered

Tags: word-request

A sellers demands a sum of money for the thing he sells and that is called 'price'. Question is, is the same on the side of a customer? I mean, does a customer offer a 'price' when he bargains? Is the word 'price' suitable when a sum of money is offered by a customer.

Comment: No. The customer "makes an offer".  The offer is the price a customer is willing to pay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An amount *offered* is normally called just that - an "offer".

If an offer is rejected then it doesn't fit the dictionary definition of "price" - "*an amount of money expected, required, or given*". But, if it is accepted then it may be referred to as the "purchase price", in contrast to the "asking price" which is the amount the seller originally asked for.

It is worth noting that in some cultures, it seems customary to *never* pay the price on the ticket and to "barter", but in most western cultures that is not the case in shops on the high street and "bartering" is not a commonly used term. It does happen in some kinds of markets, second-hand sales, and the housing market.

Comment: instead of "barter"  I think I would use the word "haggle"